# WIFI on Dell XPS 13 9343 (Broadcom BCM4352 Card) not working anymore on Debian Bookworm

Tags: firmware, iwlwifi, broadcom

I feel sorry for bringing this up again, but suddenly my WIFI adapter (Broadcom BCM4352) stopped working on my Debian Bookworm installation.

I think it stopped after an update, but I am not sure.

According to the [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Dell/Dell%20XPS%2013%209343) the package `broadcom-sta-dkms` has to be installed and it is installed. However I got a strange error from DKMS which is related to the package `firmware-iwlwifi.`

```
user@Bookworm$ sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
broadcom-sta-dkms is already the newest version (6.30.223.271-23).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up iwlwifi-3.16.2-dkms (1.0) ...
chmod: cannot access '/usr/src/iwlwifi-3.16.2-1.0/kconf/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package iwlwifi-3.16.2-dkms (--configure):
 installed iwlwifi-3.16.2-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iwlwifi-3.16.2-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to purge and reinstall the package`firmware-iwlwifi` but the error persists.

My questions are:

- How can I get rid of the  dpkg error regarding `firmware-iwlwifi`?
- How can I get my WIFI adapter working again?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got your package from, but the missing file belongs to `swupdate`.

So, I would install/upgrade `swupdate`, making sure that it belongs to the same release (bookworm). You might want to purge the current `firmware-iwlwifi` first.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install swupdate
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference to `firmware-iwlwifi` in your output snippet, but`iwlwifi-3.16.2-dkms`. It sounds like a very old version of a driver for Intel WiFi cards, which would not be applicable at all for Broadcom cards, and unlikely to work for Debian Bookworm's kernel anyway.

I would recommend `apt purge iwlwifi-3.16.2-dkms`.

Did you perhaps try various things before finding `broadcom-sta-dkms`, and maybe forgot to fully undo those failed attempts?